# Weird (?) issue with Exchange Forwarding

Tags: exchange-2003, gmail, mail-forwarding

Here is the long and short of it: the company I work for was purchased by another company who uses Gmail for domains as their email provider.  We use an in house Exchange box. No big deal, I dropped into Active Directoy and created several Contact objects that represented our new email addresses at Gmail.  I then went through each employees record and have their mail set to forward to this new address and not deliver locally. So I am forwarding email for me@domain1 to me@domain2 and this works great as long as I don't send an email from me@domain2 to me@domain1.  If I log into my personal Gmail account and send an email to me@domain1 the email is properly forwarded to me@domain2. The mail coming from me@domain2 to me@domain1 seems to just get lost in the ether.

Have I done something wrong or is this a quark with Exchange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail discards duplicate messages it receives. When you send a message from me@domain2 in Gmail to me@domain1, it gets saved in Sent Mail. The message that Gmail then receives back via the forward is a duplicate of the one in Sent Mail and therefore gets discarded.

If you want such emails to appear in the Inbox of the sender, you can add me@domain1 as a Send Mail As address to the me@domain2 Gmail account (in the Accounts tab of the Settings screen). After doing this, email sent from the me@domain2 Gmail account to me@domain1 will immediately appear in the Inbox.